# Retrieve all sharepoint objects based on sharepoint URL connected to

Tags: sharepoint

Can anyone help me in the following two scenarios.

1) If I pass the Sharepoint site url, is it possible to retrieve all sharepoint objects such as all available lists(provided by Sharepoint) and custom list(Created by user), page layouts, site layouts, web templates, site templates, sites and workspaces, libraries etc.(provided by sharepoint)) nad custom list of all above.

For he above requirement, can I use Sharepoint Object model.

Can anyone provide me a sample code.

2) Is it possible to cache(or store) the above information in an XML file so that I can use this XML as reference further.

Can anyone provide me a sample code asap?

Comment: I need this information to store in an xml file, which I am going to use later for my windows application, so that I can work offline and no need to interact with sharepoint each time when I need some information about site or any sharepoint object that I need in my application.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.aspx) is code to get a reference to an SPSite object.

The [rootweb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.rootweb.aspx) property will give you the base SPWeb object, or you can iterate through all the [AllWebs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.allwebs.aspx) if required.

The [SPWeb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.aspx) object has the [Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.lists.aspx) property you can iterate to find every list in that SPWeb.

These links should have enough code to get you going pretty quickly.

[SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/), does this all this and the code can be used subject to the GNU General Public License version 2 (GPLv2) 
 licence [here](http://spm.codeplex.com/license).

Comment: This is not what I want. I need to get the available page layouts, sites, content types, list templates and other required objects provided by sharepoint. The above info give me the information about the sites which I created in the site collection I am connecting to.